# Labels are showing in iOS but not in Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a list view with 2 labels and another list view inside of it in Xamarin.Forms.
Building for Android And iOS.

This is the particular code

```
            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {

            var grid = new Grid();



            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

            Label l = new Label() { };
            l.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("TeachersName"));
            grid.Children.Add(l);
            Label l2 = new Label() { };
            l2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("TeachersEmail"));
            grid.Children.Add(l2);
            Grid.SetRow(l, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(l2, 2);

            SfListView embeddedView = new SfListView();
            embeddedView.AutoFitMode = AutoFitMode.Height;
            embeddedView.LayoutManager = new GridLayout();
            //embeddedView.SelectionMode = Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SelectionMode.None;
            embeddedView.LayoutManager.SetBinding(GridLayout.SpanCountProperty, new Binding("NoOfCat"));
            embeddedView.SetBinding(SfListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("CatInfoSet"));
            embeddedView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var MainGrid = new Grid() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand};

                Grid Holder = new Grid() {Padding = new Thickness(5) };
                SfCircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = new SfCircularProgressBar() {Margin = new Thickness(5)};
                circularProgressBar.SetBinding(ProgressBarBase.ProgressProperty, new Binding("Percent"));
                Holder.Children.Add(circularProgressBar);

                Label label = new Label() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Description"));

                MainGrid.Children.Add(Holder);
                MainGrid.Children.Add(label);
                return MainGrid;

            });
            grid.Children.Add(embeddedView);
            Grid.SetRow(embeddedView, 0);

            return grid;
        });
```

I have a feeling its something like the row definitions that are causing the issue but can't seem to figure it out.

***Update:*** If i rearrange the grid items, placing the labels before the progress bar then they show... This is really weird

Comment: Which label is not visible in Android? It's never a good design to put a listView inside another listview.

Comment: You set the `RowDefinitions` height all to `auto` and the `listView` is in `row 0`, it  will automatically take all the space and then the labels does not appear. Try to give a absolute height to row 0 like 100 and you will see those labels under listView.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yeah I know that but I couldn't think of another way.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Oh that worked thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that we can help more people with same problem:)?

Comment: Yess Can't believe it was that simple.. I must've wasted like an hour thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `RowDefinitions` height all to `auto` and the `listView` is in `row 0`, it will automatically take all the space and then the labels does not appear. Try to give a `absolute height` to row 0 like `100` and you will see those labels under `listView`.

Something like:

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
```